# Cannot send an e-mail without a Postmark API Key

Tags: python, linux, django, python-2.7

I got this Error when user want to register:

```
PMMailMissingValueException at /accounts/register/

Cannot send an e-mail without a Postmark API Key

Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8009/accounts/register/
Django Version: 1.11.3
Exception Type: PMMailMissingValueException
```

and  I dont know to which value for

```
POSTMARK_API_TOKEN=''
```

in `settings.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what exact application you use and how you configure it, but seems it's configured to sent emails using https://postmarkapp.com/ service. You have to register and get your API access credentials.